# Remove any empty fields in a loop?

Tags: python, pandas

A list has many paths of certain csv's.
How to check if each `csv` in every loop has any empty columns and delete them if they are.

Code:

```
for i in list1:
    if (list1.columns = '').any():
        i.remove that column
```

Hope this explains what I am talking about.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Sample**:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
        '':list('abcdef'),
         'B':[4,5,4,5,5,np.nan],
         'C':[''] * 6,
         'D':[np.nan] * 6,
         'E':[5,3,6,9,2,4],
         'F':list('aaabb') + ['']
})

print (df)
        B C   D  E  F
0  a  4.0   NaN  5  a
1  b  5.0   NaN  3  a
2  c  4.0   NaN  6  a
3  d  5.0   NaN  9  b
4  e  5.0   NaN  2  b
5  f  NaN   NaN  4
```

Removed first column, because empty column name - it means filtering only columns with no empty values with [`loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) and [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
df1 = df.loc[:, df.columns != '']
print (df1)
     B C   D  E  F
0  4.0   NaN  5  a
1  5.0   NaN  3  a
2  4.0   NaN  6  a
3  5.0   NaN  9  b
4  5.0   NaN  2  b
5  NaN   NaN  4
```

Reoved column `C`, because filled only empty values - compare all values if not empty values and get at least one True per column by [`DataFrame.any`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.any.html), also filter by [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) with `loc`:

```
df2 = df.loc[:, (df != '').any()]
print (df2)
        B   D  E
0  a  4.0 NaN  5
1  b  5.0 NaN  3
2  c  4.0 NaN  6
3  d  5.0 NaN  9
4  e  5.0 NaN  2
5  f  NaN NaN  4

print ((df != ''))
            B      C     D     E      F
0  True  True  False  True  True   True
1  True  True  False  True  True   True
2  True  True  False  True  True   True
3  True  True  False  True  True   True
4  True  True  False  True  True   True
5  True  True  False  True  True  False

print ((df != '').any())
      True
B     True
C    False
D     True
E     True
F     True
dtype: bool
```

Removed column `D` because filled only missing values with function [`dropna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.dropna.html):

```
df3 = df.dropna(axis=1, how='all')
print (df3)
        B C  E  F
0  a  4.0    5  a
1  b  5.0    3  a
2  c  4.0    6  a
3  d  5.0    9  b
4  e  5.0    2  b
5  f  NaN    4
```

Comment: The first filters out columns that may not be empty but have empty field name?

Comment: @user10671234 - added sample.

Comment: is there a possibility that the two last may need swap?

Comment: @user10671234 - no, because there is difference between empty value `''` and missing value `NaN`. It is correctly.

Comment: In the boolean since F has one empty row, shouldn't it have also False in `print ((df != '').any())`?

Comment: I was talking about :`print ((df != '').any())` in the F column shouldn't be False since it has one empty row?

Comment: @user10671234 - no, because test at least one `True`. If want test all `True`s then need `print ((df != '').all())`